# Having trouble with locate while writing a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a procedure that will take a string that contains book information (title, author, publisher, etc) and will insert that data into several tables. Having not coded many of these I was trying to do the procedure piece by piece and got to this point:

```
create procedure AddBook(in details varchar(255),
out new_title varchar(255),
out new_author varchar(255),
out new_pname varchar(255),
out new_paddress varchar(255),
out new_pphone char(10),
out my_index int)
begin
    Declare title varchar(255);
    Declare author varchar(255);
    Declare pname varchar(255);
    Declare paddress varchar(255);
    Declare pphone char(10);
    Declare curIndex int;
    Declare bid int;
    Declare temp varchar(255);

    set details = trim(details);

    set curIndex = locate(',', details);
    set title = substring(details, 1, curIndex - 1);

    set temp = substring_index(details, ',', 2);
    set author = substring(temp, locate(temp, ',', 1) + 1);
```

The last line is where I got stuck. For whatever reason, locate is returning 0 even though I know temp has a comma in it. My input is

```
call AddBook('my book, George Foreman, pub4, 189, 1234567890', @title, @author, @pname, @paddress, @pphone, @index);
```

All of the out variables are for debugging and will be removed later. I found that temp ends up with the value "my book, George Foreman" yet locate can't find the comma (with or without the third parameter. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Its always the simple errors that get me. Locate takes the substring that you want to find first and then takes the string you want to search through. I passed in the parameters incorrectly.